# Enable SDL for KVM under CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to set up a VM in CentOS 7 with an SDL display, but every time I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: SDL support is disabled
```

I can't seem to figure out exactly what it means. I've installed all the SDL packages available in yum as well as changing which user qemu runs as, but nothing has gotten it to work. Has anyone else managed to get this working? Or, do I have to do something extreme like recompile qemu with SDL support (don't really want to do that as I would much rather just use yum for all packages)?

Comment: Exactly how are you starting this virtual machine? How did you create it?

Comment: I created it using virt-manager and I started it the same way. I realize this is not the only way to do it and even if there is a better way, I would like to at least understand the error. Google searches for the error message have proved unhelpful.

Comment: Hm. This really looks like one of those "should never happen" sorts of things. I'd run `package-cleanup --problems` to see if you have missing packages, and if not, file a bug report.

Comment: Maybe your QEMU is indeed compiled without SDL support.